# Interfaces with different getter and setter for the same propertie

Tags: c#, properties, interface

I've made the following declaration for interfaces:

```
public interface IBasic
{
  int Data { get; }
}

public interface IChangeable : IBasic
{
  int Data { set; }
}
```

The compiler says that `IChangeable.Data` hides `IBasic.Data`. It's reasonable. The alternative I've found is:

```
public interface IBasic
{
  int Data { get; }
}

public interface IChangeable : IBasic
{
  void ChangeData(int value);
}
```

There is any way to define setter and getters for the same property on different hierarchy on interfaces?  Or there are any alternatives to this approach?

Comment: No need to declare the property in IChangeable since all objects that implements IChangeable also must implement IBasic (due to IChangeable : IBasic)

Comment: @Simon: I've showed a simplification of the problem. On my real problem, The IBasic declares more things.

Comment: @Simon -- I made this mistake initially, too.  He wants IChangeable to add a settor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-declare it (or rather, tell the compiler that you *intend* to hide it):

```
public interface IChangeable : IBasic
{
  new int Data { set; }
}
class Foo : IChangeable
{
    private int value;
    int IBasic.Data { get { return value; } }
    int IChangeable.Data { set {this.value = value;}  }
}
```

But this is confusing, and you'll need to use explicit implementations etc, and probably a bit of casting at the caller if you want to use the hidden version. If you went this route, I would recommend exposing both the `get` and `set` on `IChangeable`:

```
public interface IChangeable : IBasic
{
    new int Data { get;  set; }
}
class Foo : IChangeable
{
    private int value;
    int IBasic.Data { get { return value; } }
    int IChangeable.Data { set { this.value = value; } get {return value; } }
}
```

---

Re the comments; to expose on the implementing type:

```
public interface IChangeable : IBasic
{
    new int Data { set; }
}
public interface IBasic
{
    int Data { get; }
}
class Foo : IChangeable
{
    private int data;
    public int Data {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
}
```

This would also work if you make it (which I prefer):

```
public interface IChangeable : IBasic
{
    new int Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In this approach, which is the way to assign value to Foo.Data?

Comment: `IChangeable c = {some foo}; c.Data = {some value};` You could also put the property on the public API, but it isn't clear from the question whether that would be the `get`, the `set`, both, etc.

Comment: I want to allow the implementor of `IChangeable` to have the `get` and `set`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've misunderstood your question but wouldn't you just do

```
public interface IChangeable : IBasic
{
  int Data { get; set; }
}
```

i.e. Let IChangeable override the property but keep the "get" present.

As IChangeable inherits from IBasic I'm assuming you want an implementation of IChangeable to have an implementation of "get".

Answer (score 1):

I think GetData and SetData methods is more clear for this situation:

```
public interface IBasic
{  
    int GetData();
}

public interface IChangeable : IBasic
{  
    void SetData(int data)
}
```

Comment: What about a read only `Data` property with a `SetData` method?